# Angular / FormBuilder Set default value for mat-select dropdown

Tags: angular, formbuilder, angular2-formbuilder

I am trying to set a default value for a dropdown in my project. I've tried several different ways of doing this, but nothing I've tried seems to work. I have tried setting the default using the `[(value)]` inside the mat-select and by using the `.setValue(...)` function on the formBuidler.  I have replicated the structure of my code in a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-default-select-ngbeek?file=app/app.component.ts). Does anyone know what I am missing or why what I currently have does not work? Any help is appreciated

Comment: Please paste your code here rather than a link to somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

I could see 2 problems in your code:

1. You need to define formBuilder instead of just define it with type

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    myForm: FormGroup;
    formBuilder: FormBuilder;   // this isn't the right definition of the class;
}
```

**this should be changed to**

```
 export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
     myForm: FormGroup;
     formBuilder: FormBuilder = new FormBuilder();  
     // or define it by constructor
     // since you are working with typescript you can define in this way
    constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }
     // typescript will transform this to  
     // constructor() { 
     //     this.formBuilder = new FormBuilder()
     // }
}
```

2. second issue is `[formGroup]="myForm"` you shoud add formGroup in your template

**check reproduction example:**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-default-select-dppuqx?file=app/app.component.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The first issue was a mistake on my my part when I created the stackblitz. The actual code I am using did define the formBuilder through a constructor. I'm not sure what you mean by #2. Could you elaborate on what I need to be adding / changing? I have updated the example to more closely match what I actually have. The <div> tag you modified with the [formGroup]="myForm" is actually a <form> tag with a corresponding submit function. Updated stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-default-select-kxzksp?file=app/app.component.html

Comment: Hi @Rattus, look your form property name is `myForm` but in the template you write `[formGroup]="basicForm"`, what is `basicForm`? It isn't defined, you need to put your actual form `myForm`. please have a look at the. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-default-select-yqzbj2?file=app/app.component.html

Comment: Thanks. That did fix the issue in the example, but now I'm not sure what else could be different between the example and the real thing

Comment: @Rattus if you can share your repo, I can take a look

Comment: Unfortunately, its a company project and something I am not able to share. Thanks for the help though

Comment: Sure,no problem, yeah I know, I am working on the company as well

Answer (score 1):

When using a `FormBuilder`, you can pass the initial value of a control as first parameter:

```js
this.formBuilder.control(initialValue, ...)
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I also tried that. I have added it to the code example now. For whatever reason, it does not seem to be working